# Image Carousel for content website

Tags: amp-html

We're using the image carousel on our AMP pages, and overall it works great.

(custom-element="amp-carousel")

However, we want to add the dots below the picture, so that as the user scrolls through the image gallery, they can see how many images are left, and which image they are on, via the little dots below the images.

It seems there is support for this feature, however when we try to turn it on, the dots don't show up beneath the images.  Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: How are you turning it on? There doesn't seem to be support documented here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-carousel/amp-carousel.md

Comment: Maybe you can add it using the caption. If this is the route you want to take, let me know what language you are using for your template and I can further explain it.

Comment: Please share the code you are trying to use.